# Getting JSON data out of dictionary within a dictionary using python

Tags: python, json, dictionary

I am using a python and getting the data from an API the data formatted as listed in the example I have a problem getting out Cust_id and name put of the API
Below is one of the things I tried and one of the things answered by SimonR. I am sure I am doing something really dumb right now but I get the error
typeError: the JSON object must be str, bytes or bytearray, not dict. Thank you everyone in advance for your answers

```
import json
a = {
  "count": 5,
  "Customers": {
    "32759": {
      "cust_id": "1234",
      "name": "Mickey Mouse"
    },
    "11053": {
      "cust_id": "1235",
      "name": "Mini Mouse"
    },
    "21483": {
      "cust_id": "1236",
      "name": "Goofy"
    },
    "12441": {
      "cust_id": "1237",
      "name": "Pluto"
    },
    "16640": {
      "cust_id": "1238",
      "name": "Donald Duck"
    }
  }
}   

d = json.loads(a)
customers = {v["cust_id"]: v["name"] for v in d["Customers"].values()}
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you're trying to do ?

```
import json
d = json.loads(a)
customers = {v["cust_id"]: v["name"] for v in d["Customers"].values()}
```

outputs :

```
{'1234': 'Mickey Mouse',
 '1235': 'Mini Mouse',
 '1236': 'Goofy',
 '1237': 'Pluto',
 '1238': 'Donald Duck'}
```

Comment: Maybe I am doing something dumb. But I get errors trying this  Below is the code

Comment: import json
a = { "count": 5, "Customers": { "32759": { "cust_id": "1234", "name": "Mickey Mouse" }, "11053": { "cust_id": "1235", "name": "Mini Mouse" }, "21483": { "cust_id": "1236", "name": "Goofy" }, "12441": { "cust_id": "1237", "name": "Pluto" }, "16640": { "cust_id": "1238", "name": "Donald Duck" } } }
d = json.loads(a)
customers = {v["cust_id"]: v["name"] for v in d["Customers"].values()}

Comment: `a` needs to be a string to call `json.loads` with it. Just add quotes (single or triple) around it : `a = '{ "count": 5, "Customers": { "32759": { "cust_id": "1234", "name": "Mickey Mouse" }, "11053": { "cust_id": "1235", "name": "Mini Mouse" }, "21483": { "cust_id": "1236", "name": "Goofy" }, "12441": { "cust_id": "1237", "name": "Pluto" }, "16640": { "cust_id": "1238", "name": "Donald Duck" } } }'`

Answer (score 0):

Well if I understood correctly you can do this:

```
# d is the API response in your post
# This will give you the list of customers
customers = d['Customers']
```

Then you can iterate over the customers dictionary and save them to any data structure you want:

```
# This will print out the name and cust_id
for k, v in customers.items():
    print(v['cust_id'], v['name'])
```

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

```py
import json

#  convert json to python dict
response = json.loads(json_string)

# loop through all customers
for key, customer in response['Customers'].items():
  # get customer id
  customer['cust_id']

  # get customer name
  custoemr['name']
```